# React Native Firebase trying to show images from Firebase Storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, expo, storage, react-native-flatlist

Once I enter in the following code I receive back two different URLs for two different images within the /Images folder. I wish to display both of these but can't seem to do so in a flatlist.
Here is my code for retrieval and any suggestions for displaying images from firebase storage are welcome.

```
    async function fetchPictures() {
    await firebase.storage().ref().child('Images').list().then(result => {
        // Loop over each item
        result.items.forEach(pics => {
            firebase.storage().ref().child(pics.fullPath).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                setUrl(url);
            })
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? First thing I can suggest is not using setUrl like that as you will always end up with the last image in the array as state instead of the entire result set.

Comment: How would you change it such that I would end up with the entire result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your state to an imageUrl array instead of a single url:

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
```

Then push onto that array when you get your results:

```
await firebase.storage().ref().child('Images').list().then(result => {
        // Loop over each item
        const imageUrls = [];
        result.items.forEach(pics => {
            firebase.storage().ref().child(pics.fullPath).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
                imageUrls.push(url);
            })
        });
        setImages(imageUrls);
    });
```

Should then be trivial to display them in your FlatList (using `images` state).